# .htacces rewrite rules for single page anchor (seo friendly)

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, seo

I have a single page website I'm using anchors to navigate through it. I want to make my anchor link SEO friendly. I'm using apache server on local host.

I would like to change:

```
http://localhost/Parllax%20Website/index.html#about
```

to

```
http://localhost/Parllax%20Website/about
```

and `index.html` to `/index`.

Comment: Doesn't this kind of defeat the entire purpose of using anchors to navigate if you have to reload the entire page every time?

Answer (score 1):

The browser will never send the anchor/hash value to the server. You can't use Apache to redirect the user.

A possible solution would be to use javascript and the [window.history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) to change the url. You would need to load the content of the page with an ajax request.